# Chi-square test on regression model

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have a regression model to build, with data having few categorical variables and my target variable is continuous. I wish to implement chi-square test for feature selection of categorical variables in my model. So converting target variable into classes and then implementing chi-sqr upon it, is a correct approach or there is any other better technique.

Comment: Why would you need to convert transform you dependent variable into a categorical one?

Comment: Chi square should be performed upon 2 categorical variables, correct me if I'm wrong. New to this field.

Comment: Is chi-square a resctriction, could you use another test?

Comment: yes you can do it after binning the continious target variable

Comment: Selecting predictors on the basis of their statistical significance in bivariate comparison is not a good approach to feature selection. Search around this website for feature selection and you'll find better recommendations.

Comment: Binning is a bad idea that involves throwing away useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad idea. Binning a continuous variable throws away information and increases both type I and type II error. It also imposes a kind of "magical thinking" - that something amazing happens at the breaks.

I'm not sure why you want to use chi-square to do feature selection.

Model building in regression is an extensive topic and has been dealt with here a lot. You will find many good answers here, but, briefly, I'd say it's best to use substantive knowledge and that if you must use an automated method (that is, you want to avoid thinking) then LASSO isn't bad.